# How to get data from browser like url, its params etc back to expo app and vice versa?

Tags: react-native, expo

So, I have been looking for a way as how to pass data between expo app and the web browser which opens as a modal within the app (not WebView). Like how to pass some data as params to the browser, or how to get data back from browser to the expo app
I have been looking through the Linking and Deep Linking documentation but they are not much helpful, please help